# MessageFormat using curly brackets {}

Tags: java, messageformat

While using MessageFormat class in Java to pass different variables in a string

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("I want to resolve this statement "{  {0}, {1}  }", "this", "this"));
```

When you print this it will show --> {  {0}, {1}  } and will not resolve arguments with values due to wrapping around curly braces.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is this:

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("I want to resolve this statement '{'{0}, {1}'}'", "this", "this"));
```

**Output**:

I want to resolve this statement {this, this}

Comment: Agreed Michael, but somehow I didn't find this solution on stack flow...wanted to share with larger group. These curly brackets stops the recognition of argument variable

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem which i want to share with larger group.
So in order to resolve same, wrap it around single quotes:

"{  '{0}', '{1}'  }"

Answer (score 0):

Please change string as below-

```
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("I want to resolve this statement {0}, {1}", "this", "this"));
```

now output will be as-

`I want to resolve this statement this, this`

curly bracket will be converted with that paramaters

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev, but in my case we can't remove outside curly braces which are conflicting, hence I came to this conclusion of resolving by using '